# Wolfram Alpha: How to evaluate the difference of a function at two points

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I'm just using the website and not the programming language or anything like that. I want to type in:

```
evaluate x from 2 to 5
```

and get `3` back as an answer, but instead it's drawing a graph and then giving me the arc length of the curve between those points. I've also tried

```
f(x)=x; f(5)-f(2)
```

but that doesn't seem to work either. Is there any built-in way to do this? Asking because it's a real pain to copy-and-paste and substitute `2` for `5` for more complicated functions that use `x` multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like

```
f(y)-f(x) substitute (x,y) = (2,5)
```

or for more complicated expressions

```
f(y)-f(x) /. {x=2,y=5}
```